# Different class objects referring same class for each index of a list

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I create different class objects referring same class for each index of a string list? I've been trying to show the matches to the user by using useradapter and recyclerview, however, I only show the last match which is the last index of my matchlist. I think the problem is about my User class object which you can see below;

```
readref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            if (snapshot.exists()) {

                List<String> matchedid = new ArrayList<>();
                matchedid = (List<String>) snapshot.get("matchlist");

                for (int i = 0; i < matchedid.size(); i++) {
                    User user = new User();

                    if (!matchedid.get(i).equals("default")) {
                        DocumentReference readref2 = usersfragmentstore.collection("users").document(matchedid.get(i));
                        readref2.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task2) {
                                DocumentSnapshot readsnap2 = task2.getResult();
                                if (readsnap2.exists()) {

                                    user.setId(readref2.getId());
                                    user.setImageURL(readsnap2.getString("imageURL"));
                                    user.setName(readsnap2.getString("name"));

                                    mUsers.add(user);

                                    usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, false);
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

This my firebase database structure;

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lOP7.jpg][1]

If I'm wrong, please help me about the problem I cannot recognize.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: I've added my database structure, but if you cannot get, let me explain. I'm using firebase firestore database so its structure is a JSON tree. I have a String list field named "matchlist" includes user id's as indexed,

Comment: Please add a more detailed one and **indicate** the exact data that you want to get.